# How to save an excel sheet I create in a python code to a desktop folder I create?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I've been struggling to save an excel sheet I create from a data frame in a folder which is created automatically on **desktop**. The excel sheet is being saved in the ide directory, but I want to move it to the desktop folder, or at least copy it :

```
import os 
import shutil
import pandas as pd 

#The data frame has been created previously 

excel_name= 'abc.xlsx'
data_frame.to_excel(excel_name,index= True)


#saving the documents in a desktop file

#Define the path to the folder where you want to move/copy the files 

folder_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop", "Excel Files Folder")

#Create the folder if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
   os.makedirs(folder_path)
     
os.path.join(folder_path, excel_name)
shutil.copy(excel_name, folder_path)
```

when doing this Im getting an error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\peha\Desktop\Excel Files Folder \abc.xlsx'

I also tried `shutil.move` but im having the same error .
Thank you for the help!

ps : I'm trying to implement it in a small software I'm creating, so I want it to work on any computer in a general way.

Comment: Try setting the path `excel_name` to `excel_name=r'C:\Users\peha\Desktop\Excel Files Folder \abc.xlsx'` for to_excel and shouldn't need to move it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) takes the entire path of the file as an argument to save it.

So you need to first create the folder, and then call `pandas.DataFrame.to_excel` to save the file using the entire path (folder + file name):

```
folder_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop", "Excel Files Folder")

if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
    os.makedirs(folder_path)

excel_name = "abc.xlsx"

data_frame.to_excel(os.path.join(folder_path, excel_name), index=True)
```